# Refresh Token for mobile app

Tags: authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0

I am trying to authenticate my ionic 2 app with oAuth2, and I can't figure out when to get new access token using refresh token.I understand that access token has expiration time, and after that time server sends invalid token error, and when i get the error a request can be sent to get new access token.But I want to know what happens when multiple background services sends request at the same time with expired access token, because all of them will return error and the client will send multiple requests to get new access token.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to get a new access token, check every HTTP request ,and just like you said, validate the token against the time constraint implemented.Well if the access token is expired it won't send any more.That is putting concurrency aside.

Comment: if  multiple services are sent at the same time, without knowing that access_token is expired because token expiration is checked in server side, they all will get invalid token error.